# how we fetch aws s3 all buckets and buckets data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3

In this post i want to ask how we can fetch all aws s3 buckets available and also i want to create s3 buckets through flutter app and want to edit/update/create/add data to all aws s3 buckets through flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "all s3 buckets" are all buckets in the AWS account the backend is running in.

A frontend application can be allowed to access AWS API directly or through various hoops.

The simplest way is to have a backend application, as backend application can easily access AWS API from "inside" AWS and deliver this through your client session to the frontend application. There is an [AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html) to retrieve all buckets.

Without a backend application the other option would be to use API Gateway and integrate with Cognito to [allow AWS API Calls](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/) for that account.
This way is much more complicated.

Comment: can you provide me any code example so i can easily understand

Comment: The links above list the HTTPs calls needed to be executed. In the end these are "simple" http calls. The more difficult thing is the authentication, but that is partially use case specific.